# My next JS app FormData() is not working in mobile browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, multipartform-data

I have a concern about my application , I have a feature that create a new product , this is working perfect in desktop browser such as chrome Mozilla inclusive Microsoft edge, the issue comes with mobile browser as chrome and Mozilla, this is my code

```
import { error, success } from "./alert";
import AxiosRequest from "../../utils/request";
// import Router from "next/router";

export const productConstants = {
  PRODUCT_ALL_BY_FEATURED: "PRODUCT_ALL_BY_FEATURED",
  CREATE_PRODUCT: "CREATE_PRODUCT",
  UPDATE_PRODUCT: "UPDATE_PRODUCT",
  DELETE_PRODUCT: "DELETE_PRODUCT",
};

export const GetProductsByFeatured = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const products = await AxiosRequest().get(
        "/product?filter=true&fields=featured&page=1&limit=50&sort=createdAt&order=-1"
      );
      dispatch({
        type: productConstants.PRODUCT_ALL_BY_FEATURED,
        products: products.data,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
};

export const AddProduct = (product, token) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {

    const form = new FormData();

    form.append("like", 0);
    form.append("taxes", product.taxes);
    form.append("receivedCar", product.receivedCar);
    form.append("featured", true);

    if (product.equipment) {
      product.equipment.map(async (item, index) => {
        form.append("equipment", item._id);
      });
    }

    form.append("model", product.model);
    form.append("brand", product.brand);
    form.append("engine", product.engine);
    form.append("year", product.year);
    form.append("category", product.category);
    form.append("state", product.state);
    form.append("price", product.price);

    if (product.files) {
      product.files.map(async (file, index) => {
        form.append("images", file);
      });
    }

    form.append("tradable", true);
    form.append("exteriorColor", product.exteriorColor);
    form.append("interiorColor", product.interiorColor);
    form.append("fuel", product.fuel);
    form.append("transmision", product.transmission);
    form.append("km", product.km);
    form.append("licensePlate", product.licensePlate);
    form.append("doors", product.doors);
    form.append("province", product.province);
    form.append("comment", product.comment);
    form.append("user", "5ff3717c916b4600174ebabe");

    try {
      const productItem = await AxiosRequest(token).post(`/product`, form);

      dispatch({
        type: productConstants.CREATE_PRODUCT,
        itemProduct: productItem.data,
      });
      dispatch(success("se ha ingresado tu carrito al portal!"));
      // Router.push("/usedCar");
    } catch (err) {

      if(err.response.status === 401){
        dispatch(error("No tienes privilegios para ingresar un nuevo chuzo!"));
      }else{
        dispatch(error("Error al ingresar tu nave!"));
      }

    }

  };
};
```

So please any comment why this happens please let me know, also I would to mention I am using node js as backend..

Comment: What part is not working? Does it hit any of your `dispatch(error())` calls?

Comment: well, I could not inspect the console in mobile browser

Comment: You could change it to `alert` which might help for debugging. You can also use remote debugging in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging?hl=en), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging), and [Safari](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/).

Comment: I will try the remote debugging if I can get more detail about the error

Comment: it throws is 422 (Unprocessable Entity)